# Question with multiple tags - which tag gets credited?

Tags: support, tagging

If I ask a question with multiple tags on it, which tag gets "credited" with that question in the stats? On the [tags page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags), do all the tags I use increase their count, or only one of them? If only one, how do you decide which?

If all of them, will tags added later through edits also be credited?

Answer (score 3):

Every tag on a question gets credit for it being there (as long as it is still on the question). So for your tags list it you have asked a question and placed a single tag on it then that tag would be increased by 1. If in a later edit that tag is removed and 5 other tags are added the original one would lose the credit and the new 5 ones would gain it.

This also goes for tag score for people who have answered the question.

As a side note the tag that shows in the page title when viewing the question is the most popular one based on amount of questions with the tag.

Answer (score 2):

You should use as many tags as the question needs to be fully covered.

**Include**

- RDBMS

  - Generic (Ex. [sql-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server))
  - Version (Ex. [sql-server-2014](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2014))
  - Technologie (Ex. [ssis](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssis))
  - Language (Ex. [tsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsql) [plsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plsql))
- Problem/Issue

  - Kind of (Ex. [repliction](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repliction) [backup](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup) [partitioning](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitioning))
  - Performance (Ex. [index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/index) [performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance))
  - Security (Ex. [security](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security))
- Design

  - Schema (Ex. [schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schema))
  - Diagram (Ex. [erd](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erd))

**Avoid**

- Hummm, I added a query let me add next tags

  - [query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/query) [select](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select)
- Oh, It's a general DB question, I'll add all DBMS

  - [sql-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) [mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql) [postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql) [oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
- I have a network issue and I can't authenticate

  - [authentication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authentication)

As a rule of thumb think:

If you'd use the search engine, under which tags should your question appear.